# using Socket.io with React and Redux to handle a hundred of updates per second

Tags: reactjs, redux, socket.io, real-time-updates

I have a list of items which are objects of data from the server (about 1000) that I need to sort, filter, put into Redux and connect to a React table component.  I'm using socket.io to listen for updates which sends these individual data objects that then need to be calculated into the table.  they can be an update, new one or, removing existing one.

So my question is what's the best way to manage so many incoming socket data events?  should i just throttle them before i update them into my redux state?  i dont want to constantly update my redux state or my table component will re-render too much.

my other option is i can request a current up to date list of all the "active" data and just ignore the update events.  so perhaps every few seconds just update the entire table with all the latest data instead of trying to manage hundreds of updates a second.

Comment: can you add some more details as to what is your present strategy? Along with the code samples of the component which renders the table.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick to using REST api calls, but faking the update on the start of a redux's action, doing nothing except maybe adding a proper id to your object on success, and reverting back the state on failure only.

Your reducer would kinda look like this in case of a create item action :

```
export default (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionsTypes.CREATE_START:
      // make the temporary changes

    case ActionsTypes.CREATE_SUCCESS:
      // update the previous temporary id with a proper id

    case ActionsTypes.CREATE_FAILURE:
      // delete the temporary changes

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And your actions like this :

```
const ActionLoading = item => ({
  type: ActionsTypes.CREATE_START,
  item,
});

const ActionSuccess = item => ({
  type: ActionsTypes.CREATE_SUCCESS,
  item ,
  createdItem,
});

const ActionFailure = item => ({
  type: ActionsTypes.CREATE_FAILURE,
  item,
});

export default todo => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(ActionLoading(item)); // add the item to your state

  const updatedTodo = await TodoClient.create(todo)

  if (updatedTodo) {
    dispatch(ActionSuccess(item, createdItem)) // update the temp item with a real id
  } else {
    dispatch(ActionFailure(item)) // remove the temporary item 
  }
};
```

It is mandatory that you give temporary ids to the data you are managing for performace's sake and to let react key properly the items rendered in maps. I personally use lodash's [uniqueId](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#uniqueId).

You'll have also to implement this behavior for updates and removals but it's basically the same:

- store the changes, update your object without waiting for the api and
  revert the changes on failure.
- remove your object without waiting for the api and pop it back on failure.

This will give a real time feel as everything will be updated instantly and only reverted on unmanaged errors. If you trust your backend enough, this is the way to go.

EDIT : Just saw your update, you can stick to this way of mutating the data (or to the normal way of updating the state on success) but to avoid too much complexity and rendering time, make sure you store your data using [keyBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#keyBy). Once your items are stored as an array of object keyed by their id, you will be able to add, remove and modify them with a O(1) complexity. Also, react will understand that it doesn't need to re-render the whole list but only the single updated item.